# Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore dotnet restore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, github-actions

I am working on an ASP.NET Web API 2 project with .NET target framework 4.6.1. I am trying to setup github workflow for my [repo](https://github.com/Team-Glare/CELT2). When the `dotnet restore` command is run, it throws an error like below.

[image]

I am getting the same error if I run the same command in from command prompt inside my project. Also if I run dotnet build, it shows below error.

[image]

The project builds fine from Visual Studio but not working from command line or [github workflow yml](https://github.com/Team-Glare/CELT2/blob/main/.github/workflows/webapi.yml). Can anyone please point me on what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

DOTNET Restore does not support pacakges.config https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore

[image]

So you have to move the nuget package references to csproj file itself

Here is a great comment on how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/a/65701746/8318698

Note: check that if multiple projectGuid is there on csproj at the end of the steps

After that you will be able to use dotnet restore without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

> The project builds fine from Visual Studio but not working from command line

Check which `sln` file Visual Studio is using to build your project.
Since I don't see any `sln`/`csproj` in your GitHub repository, it is also possible that you have a `.gitignore` which would prevent adding those in the first place.

Comment: My sln file and csproj file is both in my Github repository under the celt2/API directory.

https://github.com/Team-Glare/CELT2/blob/main/celt2/API/CELTAPI.sln

https://github.com/Team-Glare/CELT2/blob/main/celt2/API/CELTAPI/CELTAPI.csproj

Comment: @SetuKumarBasak OK, I must have missed them before.